# Android - Buttons to appear as if absolute, ignore scrolling content?

Tags: android

I have a listview populated by an adapter which, as expected, is scrollable when the content exceeds the boundaries of the page.

I also have two buttons below the list. What I want to do is have these two buttons appear at the bottom of the page right away, and remain there even if the content is scrolled, exactly like the "position: absolute" property for a website would work.

Here is the code I have... I've tried several methods but unfortunately our client wants as many pages to be created dynamically as possible, so I can't use any XML to do this, only the java class.... Hopefully one of you genius' people can help!

```
    /**
 * MaterialsActivity
 * 
 * Activity to display list of materials used for a fault.
 */
public class MaterialsActivity extends ListActivity implements DialogCloseListener {

private String faultId = null;
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
private MaterialListAdapter adapter = null;


/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.app.Activity#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)
 */

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Get data passed in (faultId)
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        faultId = extras.getString("faultId");
    }

    // Check device id valid
    if (faultId == null || faultId.length() == 0) {
        ErrorDialog ed = new ErrorDialog(this, "No fault specified");
        ed.show();
        setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
        finish();
    }

    // Set up add button and handler
    Button btnAdd = new Button(this);
    btnAdd.setText("Add New Material Entry");
    btnAdd.set
    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        //On click open add activity, passing next id to use
        //(ID system used not very robust but sticking with way existing FMS does things)
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setClassName(MaterialsActivity.this, MaterialsAddActivity.class.getName());
            intent.putExtra("faultId", faultId);
            if (adapter != null) {
                intent.putExtra("newMaterialUsedId", adapter.getNextId());
            }
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }
    }); 
    this.getListView().addFooterView(btnAdd);

    // Set up remove button and handler
    Button btnRemove = new Button(this);
    btnRemove.setText("Remove Material Entry");
    btnRemove.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        //On click open add activity, passing next id to use
        //(ID system used not very robust but sticking with way existing FMS does things)
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setClassName(MaterialsActivity.this, MaterialsRemoveActivity.class.getName());
            intent.putExtra("faultId", faultId);
            if (adapter != null) {
                intent.putExtra("newMaterialUsedId", adapter.getNextId());
            }
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
        }
    }); 
    // Add the button to the footer (needs to be done after setting it up)
    this.getListView().addFooterView(btnRemove);

    // Set list adapter
    adapter = new MaterialListAdapter(MaterialsActivity.this, R.layout.materials_list_item2, new ArrayList<MaterialsUsed>());
    setListAdapter(adapter);

    //Start new asynctask to retrieve materials list and show wait indicator
    new LoadMaterialsUsed().execute(faultId);
    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MaterialsActivity.this, "", "Loading. Please wait...", true);


}
```

The ListAdapter populates the following XML with each row from my DB table, so it runs X amount of times until it has retrieved each row.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/materialTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:paddingTop="20dp"
                android:text="Material : "
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" >

            </TextView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/matMaterial"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/materialTitle"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:paddingTop="20dp"
                android:paddingRight="15dp"
                android:textColor="#acacac"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" >

            </TextView>

           <TextView
               android:id="@+id/assetNoTitle"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_below="@id/materialTitle"
               android:gravity="left"
               android:text="Asset No : "
               android:paddingTop="5dp"
               android:textSize="15sp"
               android:textStyle="bold" >

           </TextView>

           <TextView
               android:id="@+id/matAssetNo"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_toRightOf="@id/assetNoTitle"
               android:layout_below="@id/matMaterial"
               android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
               android:gravity="right"
               android:paddingTop="5dp"
               android:paddingRight="15dp"
               android:textColor="#acacac"
               android:textSize="15sp" >

            </TextView>

           <!-- <TextView
               android:id="@+id/equipmentTitle"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_below="@id/assetNoTitle"
               android:gravity="left"
               android:text="Equipment : "
               android:textSize="15sp"
               android:paddingTop="5dp"
               android:textStyle="bold" >

           </TextView>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/matEquipment"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/equipmentTitle"
                android:layout_below="@id/matAssetNo"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="15dp"
                android:textColor="#acacac"
                android:textSize="15sp" >

           </TextView> -->

           <TextView
               android:id="@+id/manufacturerTitle"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_below="@id/assetNoTitle"
               android:gravity="left"
               android:text="Manufacturer : "
               android:textSize="15sp"
               android:paddingTop="5dp"
               android:textStyle="bold" >
               </TextView>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/matManufacturer"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/manufacturerTitle"
                android:layout_below="@id/matAssetNo"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="15dp"
                android:textColor="#acacac"
                android:textSize="15sp" >

            </TextView>

           <TextView
               android:id="@+id/modelTitle"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_below="@id/manufacturerTitle"
               android:gravity="left"
               android:text="Model : "
               android:textSize="15sp"
               android:paddingTop="5dp"
               android:textStyle="bold">

           </TextView>

           <TextView
               android:id="@+id/matModel"
               android:layout_width="100dp"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
               android:layout_below="@id/matManufacturer"
               android:layout_toRightOf="@id/modelTitle"
               android:gravity="right"
               android:paddingTop="5dp"
               android:paddingRight="15dp"
               android:textColor="#acacac"
               android:textSize="15sp" >

            </TextView>

           <!--  <TextView
               android:id="@+id/descriptionTitle"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_below="@id/modelTitle"
               android:gravity="left"
               android:text="Description : "
               android:textSize="15sp"
               android:paddingTop="5dp"
               android:textStyle="bold">

           </TextView>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/matDescription"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@id/matModel"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/descriptionTitle"
                android:textColor="#acacac"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="15dp" 
                android:textSize="15sp" >

           </TextView> -->

            <TextView
               android:id="@+id/serialNoTitle"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_below="@id/modelTitle"
               android:gravity="left"
               android:text="Serial No : "
               android:textSize="15sp"
               android:paddingTop="5dp"
               android:paddingBottom="20dp"
               android:textStyle="bold">

           </TextView>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/matSerialNo"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/serialNoTitle"
                android:layout_below="@id/matModel"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="15dp"
                android:paddingBottom="20dp"
                android:textColor="#acacac"
                android:textSize="15sp">

            </TextView>

           <!--  <TextView
               android:id="@+id/modifiedByTitle"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_below="@id/serialNoTitle"
               android:gravity="left"
               android:text="Modified By : "
               android:textSize="15sp"
               android:paddingTop="5dp"
               android:textStyle="bold">

           </TextView>
           <TextView
               android:id="@+id/matModifiedBy"
               android:layout_width="130dp"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_toRightOf="@id/modifiedByTitle"
               android:layout_below="@id/matSerialNo"
               android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
               android:gravity="right"
               android:paddingTop="5dp"
               android:paddingRight="15dp"
               android:textColor="#acacac"
               android:textSize="15sp" >

            </TextView>

            <TextView
               android:id="@+id/modifiedTimeTitle"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_below="@id/modifiedByTitle"
               android:gravity="left"
               android:text="Modified Time : "
               android:textSize="15sp"
               android:paddingTop="5dp"
               android:paddingBottom="20dp"
               android:textStyle="bold">

           </TextView>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/matModifiedTime"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/modifiedTimeTitle"
                android:layout_below="@id/matModifiedBy"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="15dp"
                android:paddingBottom="20dp"
                android:textColor="#acacac"
                android:textSize="15sp" >

           </TextView>                  -->
           <View 
               android:background="@drawable/white"
               android:layout_height="2dp"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: The only XML code is what my list adapter uses to draw in information, everything else is created dynamically in the Java above... the page itself is very simple. One listview (populated from DB), followed by two buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you could change the XML where `ListView` resides in, it would be dead easy.

Since you can't, you'll need to use a few hacks. Here's a step by step plan:

1. Add the button to the ListView's parent layout.
2. Measure the button's height
3. Then wait for the ListView to be drawn so you can measure it's height.
4. Finally set the ListView's height so the button is visible (not overlayed by the list)

Here's a sample I've tried:

```
ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) listView.getParent();

Button button = new Button(this);
button.setText("Button");
button.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
viewGroup.addView(button);

// Button height
button.measure(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
final int buttonHeight = button.getHeight();
Log.e("TAG", "Button height: " + buttonHeight);

// ListView height
listView.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new View.OnLayoutChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom,
                               int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {
        listView.removeOnLayoutChangeListener(this);
        int listHeight = listView.getMeasuredHeight();
        Log.e("TAG", "List height: " + listHeight);

        // ListView's height = listHeight - buttonHeight
        listView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, listHeight - buttonHeight));
    }
});
```

*Notes:*

- This sample assumes that the ListView's parent is a LinearLayout.
- It will add the button after every other in the parent layout.
- If, however, the parent is a RelativeLayout, you'll have to play around with `layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BOTTOM_OF, listView.getId());`

Comment: Thats got it! You Sir have allowed me to get home 30 minutes early today. Thank you!

Comment: If I had more rep (rarely use Stack Overflow) I'd upvote the answer too, but still too much of a newbie it seems!

Answer (score 0):

in your xml you have to do something like this...

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >


    <ListView 
        android:layout_above="@+id/ll_buttons">

    </ListView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_buttons"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

this will set your buttons on bottom of screen always and the list view will always be above the LinearLayout  containing the list items(i.e ofcourse scrollable).

For Dynamic buttons.. add in layout

```
Button button = new Button(this) ///this is a context object

   button.setWidth(100);
   button.setText("Save");


   layout.addView(button);
```

Comment: I'm a little confused. I have no XML for this activity, only Java. The closest XML I have is a ListAdapter, which if I place my buttons inside of it, they will be produced X amount of times dependant on how many list items are created from my DB Rows?

Comment: are these buttons also generated dynamicaly in you adapter? or these are fixed buttons on screen?

Comment: I think I may have explained it a little poorly. I have an activity for the page, which creates the two buttons. It also places a call to a ListAdapter activity which draws in a list of information.

What I need, is the buttons to constantly appear at the bottom of the screen, even when the content is scrolled.

Comment: okay so the listadapter must be putting data in some listview rit?

Comment: EDIT: I've posted the XML code that my listadapter uses. As I mentioned, the buttons are irrelevant in regards to it :/

Comment: add the button to the layout and not the listview, maybe thats the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your xml looks somthing like this

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"> 
    <ListView>
        ...
    </ListView>
   <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button />
        <Button />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I would not use a `ListView` but a `LinearLayout` inside of a ScrollView and dynamically add `TextView` item to the Layout

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical">
    <ScrollView>
        <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView />
            <TextView />
            ...
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
   <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button />
        <Button />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

you just need to add all missing attributes like `weights`, `width`,`height` etc

**edit:**
The idea is the same if would generate all views with java code instead of an XML defenition

Comment: Thats how I would have approached it if I had built the activity the normal route (using XML for layout), but the entire thing is built within the activity... the only XML is to lay out how the list appears... The buttons are handled completely by the activity, no actual XML attached to them.

Comment: @JayPaleschi using the xml would be the easiest way. Why don't you define the buttons in the XML ? As far as I understood they are alyways at the same position right ?

Comment: It was a call from someone in a much higher position than myself I'm afraid. They want it all making dynamically.

The XML used by the listadapter can't create them simply 'cause it runs X amount of times (once for each row in the DB table it produces), so I'd be left with way too many buttons heh.